# Can one iOS app purchase in-app non-renewable subscription products defined in another app (same vendor)?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have several iOS apps that all use the same subscriptions to supply functionality such as sync and other features.  The in-app purchase items will be non-renewable subscriptions, therefore Apple only handles the payment, I have to track the subscription on my servers.  With this being the case I don't see why I need to duplicate the catalog for each app.  If I pair the in-app ID's (unique identifiers for each subscription) with one product, and I make that catalog of ID's available as a web service so any of my apps can retrieve the list of bundle ID's, is there any reason app B can't purchase in-app products (non-renewable subscriptions) created in iTunes connect for app A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the app store quick reference (https://developer.apple.com/appstore/in-app-purchase/In-App-Purchase-Guidelines.pdf):

"• In-App Purchase items cannot be shared across applications or platforms."